# Codeception set custom html report file name

Tags: report, codeception

Running tests with key
    *--html*                **Generate html with results (default: "report.html")**
generates html report named report.html.
How can I set another name for html report file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added name.html after --html and recieved name.html report